# Sqlalchemy: joinedload + limit

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, subquery, limit

Given the following statement:

```
p = db.query(Profile).options(joinedload('*')).filter_by(id=p.id).limit(1).one()
```

I will get a subquery + a join, instead of a "pure" join:

```
SELECT [...] 
FROM (SELECT profile.id AS profile_id, ...
FROM profile 
WHERE profile.id = %(id_1)s 
LIMIT %(param_1)s) AS anon_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN city AS city_1 ON city_1.id = anon_1.profile_city LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS country_1 ON country_1.id = city_1.country LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_1 ON country_1.id = state_1.country LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_2 ON state_2.id = city_1.state LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS country_2 ON country_2.id = state_2.country LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_3 ON state_3.id = city_1.state LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS country_3 ON country_3.id = state_3.country LEFT OUTER JOIN starred AS starred_1 ON anon_1.profile_id = starred_1.star LEFT OUTER JOIN profiletext AS profiletext_1 ON anon_1.profile_id = profiletext_1.profile LEFT OUTER JOIN starred AS starred_2 ON anon_1.profile_id = starred_2.idprofile LEFT OUTER JOIN photo AS photo_1 ON anon_1.profile_id = photo_1.profile LEFT OUTER JOIN gps AS gps_1 ON anon_1.profile_id = gps_1.idprofile
```

but what I really need is:

```
SELECT ...
FROM profile LEFT OUTER JOIN city AS city_1 ON city_1.id = profile.city LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS country_1 ON country_1.id = city_1.country LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_1 ON country_1.id = state_1.country LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_2 ON state_2.id = city_1.state     
LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS country_2 ON country_2.id = state_2.country LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_3 ON state_3.id = city_1.state LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS country_3 ON country_3.id = state_3.country LEFT OUTER JOIN starred AS starred_1 ON profile.id = starred_1.star LEFT OUTER JOIN profiletext AS profiletext_1 ON profile.id = profiletext_1.profile LEFT OUTER JOIN starred AS starred_2 ON profile.id = starred_2.idprofile LEFT OUTER JOIN photo AS photo_1 ON profile.id = photo_1.profile LEFT OUTER JOIN gps AS gps_1 
ON profile.id = gps_1.idprofile                                                                                                                                                                                                    
WHERE profile.id = 4 
limit 1;
```

i.e. no subquery.

database: postgresql 9.2

Answer (score 3):

This seems like expected behavior according to [The Zen of Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-eager-loading)

> When using joined eager loading, if the query contains a modifier that
>   impacts the rows returned externally to the joins, such as when using
>   DISTINCT, LIMIT, OFFSET or equivalent, the completed statement is
>   first wrapped inside a subquery, and the joins used specifically for
>   joined eager loading are applied to the subquery. SQLAlchemy’s joined
>   eager loading goes the extra mile, and then ten miles further, to
>   absolutely ensure that it does not affect the end result of the query,
>   only the way collections and related objects are loaded, no matter
>   what the format of the query is.

I realize this is an old question, but is there a reason the generated SQL doesn't work?

Comment: Does this mean that if there's a query with limit/distinct/offset with joinedload somewhere in the query, then the joinedload is treated as a subqueryload?

Comment: It seems like that's the case, yes. I'm not sure if the internals of sqlalchemy transform it into a [subqueryload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload) or not, but it seems like it has the same outcome.